# jQuery load doesn't work as I expected

Tags: jquery

```
$(".content")
        .load("content/intro.html #bt")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .load("content/intro.html #ofm")
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .load("content/main.html")
        .fadeIn(800);
```

I would expect that jQuery first load content (`intro.html #bt` etc.) but it will actually load `main.html` and than will do everything other on the list. In this case three times fade in an out. What is workaround?

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is. Please be more clear. Do you want to affect three separate sections? If so, you can define an anonymous function that does the three fade in and out in sequence.

Comment: i want jq to first load intro.html #bt, than intro.html #ofm and than main.html but it will load only main.html and do every fadeIn and fadeOut on the list. all that should be in one section

Comment: Why not have them in separate statements?

Answer (score 4):

It might be counter-intuitive but makes a lot of sense when you understand how jQuery works.

All the methods you're calling are starting at the same time. So it loads all three html pages but your eyes are only seeing the last one, and then you're seeing the animations kick in. You need to tell jQuery to wait for each command to finish before executing the next one.

(What you are doing is called *chaining*, and though it's [quite useful](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/), it doesn't work like you want it to, and it's not what you need here.)

The flow of execution can be controller by using either callbacks or the [deferred pattern](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). jQuery implements both (deferred only since v1.5 I believe) but [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) only implements callbacks.

Basically, you're telling jQuery to load stuff and run animations, but you're *not* telling it to wait for the previous command to be finished before continuing.

Here's one way of achieving what you want. I haven't tested it but it demonstrates the principle.

```
$(".content")
    .load("content/intro.html #bt", function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn(2000, function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                $(this).load("content/intro.html #ofm", function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(2000, function() {
                        $(this).fadeOut(2000, function() {
                            $(this).load("content/main.html", function(){
                                $(this).fadeIn(800);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Notice how each method has a callback? That way you know that execution of the previous method is finished before you continue.

Note, this code is far from ideal! There are better ways of achieving this pattern with the [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) pattern and one of [the many jQuery pulse plugins](https://www.google.com.au/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery%20pulse).

Once you've understood why jQuery works this way, check out [Paul irish's post on how to address the ugly syntax this creates](http://paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/).

You might also want check-out [TameJS](http://tamejs.org/) which adds a construct called `await` to javascript allowing to simplify this kind of code.

Comment: yes your wright but to me my code have sense :D but true this is not how jquery works and i must learn it much better, thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my two cents:

It is possible to chain these things (in a way) with a helper.  I always wanted to be able to chain animations and loads together, and so after reading your question, and finally deciding to dig down deep to finally figure out how I might chain these things, this is what I came up with.

```
function Resolver () {
    this.itemsToResolve = [];
    this.context = {};  
    //this.context is only needed if you want to pass 
    //something to the next anonymous function
    this.next = function(){ 
        var def = $.Deferred();
        def.then.apply(def,arguments);
        this.itemsToResolve.push(def);
        return this;
    };
    this.resolveNext = $.proxy(function(){
        var p = this.itemsToResolve.shift();
        if (p){
            p.resolve(this);
        }           
    }, this);
 };
```

Strictly speaking, I probably didn't even need to use jQuery's deferred(s), but I was trying to work on something that could use them to their full potential--if that makes any sense, I'm not sure it makes any sense to me!

With that helper, here's your code modified to work with it:

```
 var $c = $(".content");
 var res = new Resolver();
 res.next(function(r){
    $c.load("content/intro.html #bt",r.resolveNext);
 }).next(function(r){
    $c.hide()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .delay(2000)
    .fadeOut(2000,r.resolveNext);
 }).next(function(r){
    $c.load("content/intro.html #ofm",r.resolveNext);    
 }).next(function(r){
    $c.fadeIn(2000)
    .fadeOut(2000, r.resolveNext);
 }).next(function(r){
    $c.load("content/main.html",r.resolveNext);  
 }).next(function(r){
    $c.fadeIn(800, r.resolveNext);
 });
 //and then finally, to start it off
 res.resolveNext();
```

There's probably a more refined way to do this, but but otherwise, I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: If you're happy with an answer, don't forget to accept it :-D