# jQuery sequentially render items fetched from ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, sequential

I have a page displaying listings of objects. Each of these listings come from an ajax call. How do I go about making sure they are rendered sequentially?

Ive tried using the technique shown [here](http://charliedigital.com/2011/07/15/chaining-jquery-ajax-calls/), but incase one of the requests fails, it rejects the remaining. My data isnt dependant on the previous, so how do I go about modifying the example, and handling errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964476/jquery-load-doesnt-work-as-i-expected/9967897#9967897), I wrote this little Resolver class, but I like this idea of piping.  I don't know that I like the example so much, but with a little tweaking, I think it'll work just fine.  I'll admit, I have yet to test this, though.

```
var urls = ["path1","path2","path3"]; // Output from string.split()
var chain = $.Deferred(); // Create the root of the chain.
var promise = chain; // Placeholder for the promise

// Build the chain
jQuery.each(urls,function(index,elem){
    // Pipe the response to the "next" function
    promise = promise.pipe(function(response)
    {
        var myurl = elem; // Get the current part
        var newPromise = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax 
        ({
           type: "GET",
           url: myurl
        }).done(function(data){  
          //these are your normal ajax success function params, IIRC
           //do stuff with response
        }).fail(function(){
           //oops, it failed, oh well
           //do stuff on failure 
        }).always(function() {
           //but always resolve the sequencing promise
           newPromise.resolve();            
        });
        return newPromise;
    })
});

chain.resolve();
```

EDIT: here's a JSFiddle with simulated ajax requests http://jsfiddle.net/jfcox/gFLhK/.  As you can see, it all sequences up.

EDIT II: slight tweaks in comments.  note you should be able to pass in info to your next promise by passing in whatever to your resolve invocations...

EDIT III: modified per Dave's suggestion.  To further separate concerns, you can use `always` on the ajax request.

Comment: Maybe use .always() for newPromise.resolve()?  (I really need to mess around with this stuff more.)

Comment: The point of the resolve is to resolve the current promise in the chain of promises (which you'll always want resolved whether or not the ajax/ajax promise suceeds (is resolved) or fails (is rejected).  But you do bring up a good point.  Instead of being required to resolve the promise after your done/fail code, you can put it in it's own `always` invocation and further separate out that concern.

Comment: If you mean to chain with always, like, as in replacing the `pipe` invocation with `always`...well,  I think the problem is always always returns the orignal promise, whereas pipe always returns a new one.  I might be wrong about that, though.

Comment: I meant to use it on the jqXHR object returned by $.ajax(), like so: http://jsfiddle.net/gFLhK/2/

Comment: Even if this doesn't turn out to be the answer (although I suspect it will) I think I finally have a handle on how $.Deferred is supposed to work, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the list of responses in an array

```
function response () {
   responseArray[i] = response; // Where i is the sequence number of request and response;
   responseHandler(); // Ping some function which can take the response in the order and process it.
}
```

Comment: I havent completely understood your reply, so please correct me if im wrong, but in this case, wont I have to wait for all the requests to complete before rendering them?

Comment: no as soon as you received response responseHandler() function will be called that function will parse the data.

Comment: I don't think that answers the OPs question.  Ajax responses can come out of order of their requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery.when?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/94PGy/4/

In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred. Note that some of the Deferreds may still be unresolved at that point. If you need to perform additional processing for this case, such as canceling any unfinished ajax requests, you can keep references to the underlying jqXHR objects in a closure and inspect/cancel them in the failCallback.